# Double sum in Python

Tags: python, numpy, sum

I am now programming on BFGS algorithm, where I need to create a function with a doulbe sum. I need to return a **FUNCTION** but not a number, so something like `sum+=` is not acceptable.

```
def func(X,W):
    return a function of double sum of X, W
```

A illustrative example:

```
X = np.array([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4],[5,5,5,5]])  
W = np.array([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3]])
```

I want to get a function that, for each instance `X[i]` in `X`, and for each `W[j]` in `W`, return a function of the sum of `numpy.dot(X[i],W[j])`. For example, `X[1]` dot `W[2]` shoulde be `2*3+2*3+2*3+2*3`

----------This contend is edited by me:-------------

When I saw the answers provided below, I think my question is not clear enough. Actually, I want to get a function:

```
Func = X[0]W[0]+X[0]W[1]+X[0]W[2]+ X[1]W[0]+X[1]W[1]+X[1]W[2]+ 
X[2]W[0]+X[2]W[1]+X[2]W[2]+ X[3]W[0]+X[3]W[1]+X[3]W[2] + 
X[4]W[0]+X[4]W[1]+X[4]W[2]
```

-------------------end the edited content--------------

If I only got one dimension of `W`, the problem is easy by using `numpy.sum(X,W)`.

However, how can I return a function of two sums with Python?

Comment: Would you want one ore many returned functions ? Can you precise the parameters of the returned function(s) ? When do you decide which parts of X and W you want to sum ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return the function f(i,j) -> X[i].W[j] :

```
def func(X,W):
    def f(i,j): return np.dot(X[i],W[j])
    return f
```

will work.

**EDIT:**

The **VALUE** you name `Func` in your edit is computed by `sum([np.dot(x,w) for x in X for w in W])`  or, more efficient,  `np.einsum('ij,kj->',X,W)` .
if you want to return the **FUNCTION** that return `Func`, you can do it like that :

```
def func(X,W):
    Func=np.einsum('ij,kj->',X,W)
    return lambda : Func
```

Then `f=func(X,W); print(f())` will print `360`, the value named  `Func` in your example.

Comment: I edited my questions, actually I want to get a function like that. I tried your comments, but failed. Could you please have a look again? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right, this should do exactly what you want (python-2.7):

```
import numpy as np

def sample_main():
    X = np.array([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4],[5,5,5,5]])  
    W = np.array([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3]])

    f = lambda i, j : reduce (lambda a, b: a+b, map(lambda x, w: x*w, X[i], W[j]), 0)
    return f


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = sample_main()
    print (f(0, 0))
```

Just replace the sample_main function with your function that takes X and W.

Comment: I edited my questions, actually I want to get a function like that. Could you please have a look again? Thank you very much.

Comment: In your code, I want to get  a function of f(0,0)+f(0,1)+f(0,2)+f(1,0)+f(1,1)+f(1,2)+...+f(4,2).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I want to implement L_BFGS algorithm in my Python code. Inspired by the two answers provided by @B.M. and @siebenschlaefer, I figure out how to implement in my code:

```
func =  np.sum(np.sum(log_p_y_xz(Y[i][t], Z[i], sigma_eta_ti(X[i],w[t],gamma[t]))+log_p_z_x(alpha, beta, X[i]) for t in range(3)) for i in range (5))
```

Please do not mind the details of the formula, what I want to say is that, I use two `sum` here and just using `i in rage (5)` and `t in range (3)` to tell the code do the sums.

Thanks again for the answers provided by @B.M. and @siebenschlaefer!!